# how to remove previous marker in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my geocoder google map code
MY code work when i change the select option
the marker is add in map, when i select multiple places,
i want to remove previous marker.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Geocoding service</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
 }
 #panel {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -180px;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
 }</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
 var geocoder;var map;
  function initialize() {
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.9252007,78.1197754);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,center: latlng
      }   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }
     function codeAddress() {
     var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
     } else {
     alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }}); }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>
      </head><body>
      <div align="center" verticle-align="ce">
      <form method="get" action="">
      <select name="address" id="address" onChange="codeAddress()" >
      <option value="chennai,india">chennai,india</option>
      <option value="madurai,india">madurai,india</option>
      <option value="bangalore,india">bangalore,india</option>
      <option value="delhi,india">Delhi</option>
      </select>
       </form> </div>
     <div id="map-canvas" style="width:750px;height:500px;"></div>
     </body></html>
```

working of the code:
when i load the page ,it automatic load the initial place, i change the option  value it will load the choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `marker` as global variable, move marker definition to `initialize()` function and on change of selection set position using `marker.setPosition()`:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.9252007,78.1197754);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }; 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map
    });
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var position = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(position);

            marker.setPosition(position);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nelogo/1/edit).